# clarification on import * as x from vs import x from for moment

Tags: typescript, webpack, requirejs, momentjs, parceljs

From moments own documentation `https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/`

it's recommended to use `import * as moment from 'moment';`

This also has no intellisense errors according to typescript compiler when using the included definitions of their project.

However, when building/bundling with parceljs, a `console.log(moment)` would give a runtime error `moment is not a function`

Looking at the variable moment, it has a `default` property.

One would then know that i can fix my problem with `import moment from "moment"`and also whats recomended here on an issue with parceljs. `https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1194#issuecomment-381488271`

That, however, will lead to an intellisense error that it has no default export.

Then the cycle repeats, leading back to the start of moment documentation of using the `import * as`.

In my own projects where I use requirejs, everything works. I can `import * as moment` and moment is the function (not an object).

Is this an error on moments behalf that they should fix their typing file?
is this an error on parceljs on how it bundle?
Is it related to amd modules vs commonjs?

I accept that we can work around the problem is many ways. I am not looking for a fix - but understanding where the problem is so it can be fixed

Comment: when you use moment with parceljs you get this problem?

Comment: if you do import * as moment from "moment", then thats valid typescript but will break at runtime when used with parceljs.  But i think the trick is "esModuleInterop" introduced in 2.7 ts. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html

Comment: please tell me this, why would you use parceljs when you use webpack?

Comment: This is a ParcelJS bug. `import * as moment from 'moment'` is the recommended way, works in Webpack, and should work in ParcelJS.

Comment: It's kind of *"the fault"* of moment for structuring its code as a single root function instead of importable submodules, but ParcelJS should still handle that.